# Saying Kiddush Levanah without a Minyan

Tags: halacha, number, minyan, kiddush-levanah

If one does not have the opportunity to say Kiddush Levanah with a Minyan, should he say it alone?  If he can say it with a group of people that is less than 10, is that better than saying it by himself, and if so, is a larger number (under 10) better (meaning 3 is better than 2, 8 is better than 7)?

Comment: Do you have any reason to suspect the number 10 is at all relevant?

Comment: @DoubleAA other than the fact that it is usually tied to the end of Ma'ariv and the fact that generally it is followed by 'Aleinu and Kaddish? No.

Comment: Maariv is also usually followed by Aleinu, but no one thinks that needs a minyan.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that's true. But it is preferable to say Ma'ariv with a Minyan. And I didn't ask if it needs one, I asked if one still should say it without one. Is it an individual requirement?

Comment: I'm just saying the question would be improved if you indicate why you might think 10 would be a requirement or even preferable.

Comment: @DoubleAA why would this question require that explanation any more than the same question about Ma'ariv?

Comment: They require it the same... If someone was asking if Maariv could be said without a Minyan, I would also ask why they think a Minyan is relevant. They might answer: because I always see it done with a Minyan. If that's their basis it should be [edit]ed into the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Beiur Halacha ([OC 456 sv Ella](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49626&st=&pgnum=184&hilite=)) writes that it certainly permitted to recite it alone, though ideally it should be done with others because of the principle of Berov Am Hadrat Melech. He quotes two opinions if a group of 3 or 10 counts for that.

Comment: Isn't the usual/general/simple understanding of "rov am hadres melech" when multiple people have to make the same bracha and one person does it for all of them?

Comment: @Yehoshua Seems reasonable

Comment: So "rov am hadras melech" the "pashut" understanding is that a mitzvah is done individually however in one big group?

Comment: @Yehoshua Perhaps they are different levels of BeRov Am?

Comment: Aruch HaShulchan 273:6 ופשוט הוא, דזהו כשהם אינם יכולים בעצמם לעשות קידוש. אבל כשיכולים בעצמם לקדש - אין לו לקדש בעדם כשהוא לא יצא בקידוש זה. אבל אם גם הוא צריך לקידוש זה - מוטב שיקדש הוא ויוציא את כולם, משיקדש כל אחד בעצמו, אף על פי שכל אחד יכול לקדש לעצמו, משום 'ברוב עם הדרת מלך' (ברכות נ"ג.), וכמ"ש בסימן רצ"ח ע"ש, וכן הוא המנהג בהרבה מקומות.

Comment: @Yehoshua Indeed. However, consider Sefirat HaOmer where counting at a Minyan is discussed as Berov Am, but everyone counts individually. You're making a good point still.

Comment: Can you give me a makor for that? (I'm this question together for a friend and it would help.)